# Using norm Function In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance, norm

I have a matrix of data which is the coordinates of some points and coordinates of 5 clusters

```
data = [randi(100,100,1),randi(100,100,1)];
x_Clusters = [20 5 12 88 61];
y_Clusters = [10 50 14 41 10];
Coordinates_Of_Clusters = [x_Clusters',y_Clusters'];
```

I want to use norm function to determine the distances from the centers of 5 known clusters which are the above coordinates to my data. How could I do that?

Comment: You need to use `norm(X)` if you want to compute the 2-norm, Euclidean distance. Matlab uses the 2-norm by default.

Comment: Why do you want to use `norm` for this? It’s n out particularly suited.

Comment: `pdist2` in the statistics toolbox does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The funtion `norm(X)` is the same as `norm(X,2)`. Matlab uses the 2-norm (Euclidean distance) by default.

Using your code to begin:

```
% number of data points (trying to harcode less values)
n_points = 100;

data = [randi(n_points,n_points,1),randi(n_points,n_points,1)];
x_Clusters = [20 5 12 88 61];
y_Clusters = [10 50 14 41 10];
Coordinates_Of_Clusters = [x_Clusters',y_Clusters']; 

% number of clusters 
n_clusters = size(Coordinates_Of_Clusters,1);

% option 1: output is 100-by-10
output_matrix_100x10 = zeros(n_points,2*n_clusters);

% option 2: output is 500-by-2
output_matrix_500x2  = zeros(n_points*n_clusters,2);
```

Then use for loops for all clusters (`n_clusters`) and for each point (`n_points`):

```
for n = 1:n_clusters
    for i = 1:n_points

        % option 1
        output_matrix_100x10(i,(n-1)*2+1:(n-1)*2+2) = ...
            norm(data(i,:)-Coordinates_Of_Clusters(n,:), 2);

        % option 2
        output_matrix_500x2((n-1)*n_points+i,1:2) = ...
            norm(data(i,:)-Coordinates_Of_Clusters(n,:), 2);

    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but it's not what I want.I want The Distance between my data and centers of clusters which was Coordinates_of_Clusters as shown above in my question

Comment: I understand now, I will edit my response above. And then the 2-norm will be the distance between x1 and x2, given by ((x1-x2)^2)^0.5, also known as the Euclidean distance. This holds for higher dimensions as well.

Comment: I Copied This Code But I Got Matrix Dimension Error.Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Hw_Yek (line 24)
    dist = norm(Data-Coordinates_Of_Clusters(i,:),2)

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? is the variable `data` or `Data`? The code works for me when I copy it. Do you have other variables that may overwrite these?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2013

Comment: Copy and past this ‘size([randi(100,100,1), randi(100,100,1)])’ in the command window and tell me what you get in R2013.

Comment: I Copied It And It Worked.ans =

   100     2

Comment: So for your `100`-by`2` matrix, R2013 doesn't want to compute the 2-norm, but you can go through another loop. I edited my response. After your compute the distance (using 2-norm) for each point to a cluster, you can compute the average or sum of the distance for all the points.

Comment: `norm` with a matrix input computes the norm for the matrix, not for each column separately. Use `vecnorm` instead.

Comment: Actually, I want 500*2 Matrix Which Each Row Shows The Distance Between Each Data to each Center of Cluster.Another Explanation is that We Want to Measure The Distance Between All Data To First Cluster Center, It Will Be a 100*2 Matrix.(Distance Between each Data to The Center of first Cluster).So,For 5 Clusters,The Results Should Be a 500*2 Matrix.For Better exhibition,It Will Be Awesome If The Matrix Be 100*10.The First 2 Column Shows Distance Between Data and First Cluster Center,The Second 2 Column Shows The Distance Between Data And Second Cluster Center And So On.

Comment: Sounds good, it makes more sense now. I changed my solution answer and it works. I gave you 2 options: 1) output is 500*2, and 2) output is 100*10. One last thing: the `norm` distance is a single number, so you could reduce it to 500*1 or 100*5 (right now, the columns are duplicate)

Comment: Thank You so much.It Worked.But Can You Explain To Me This Term :
output_matrix_100x10(j,(i-1)*2+1:(i-1)*2+2)

Comment: Of course, `(i, (n-1)*2+1:(n-1)*2+2)` is meant to index your output matrix for each norm you compute inside the loop . row = `i`, so that's easy, you go through 100 points total. Your first data point will be placed in row 1, 2nd point in row 2 and so on. column = `(n-1)*2+1:(n-1)*2+2` is more difficult, but basically, it will shift the column index by 2 every time you go to the next cluster. `n` in this case designates which cluster you are computing the norm for. For the first cluster: `n = 1`, so column = `1:2` (the result is placed in colums 1 and 2)...

Comment: For the second cluster, `n = 2`, so column = `3:4` and so on. That's why the output matrix is 100x10. But since columns 1 and 2 are the same, 3 and 4 are the same and so on, you could just reduce it to 100x5. If you want to do that, just change `output_matrix_100x10(i,(n-1)*2+1:(n-1)*2+2) = ...` to `output_matrix_100x5(i,n) = ...` This will be more efficient and looks simpler :)

Comment: If that works, consider accepting the solution answer.